# How to remove all untracked git files/folders except the ignored ones?

Tags: git, gitignore

I do see some related questions but I haven't found the solution for my specific case. In my situation, I got some untracked files and folders (not git-ignored), and some other files and folders declared in `.gitignore`. I want to remove all the non-git-ignored, untracked files and folders, and keep all the git-ignored ones.

If I use `git clean -f`, the untracked files will be gone, while the folders remain. In case of running `git clean -df`, git-ignored folders will be deleted together with non-git-ignored ones.

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about `git clean`'s options.

- `git-clean -d` cleans directories as well as files.
- `git-clean -x` prevents git from processing `.gitignore`
- `git-clean -X` *only* removes ignored files
- `git-clean -f` is just a force option.

So the default behaviour of `git clean -df` is to remove files and folders *except* those which are ignored. That seems to be what you are asking for.

Demonstration:

```
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git$ mkdir tmp
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git$ cd tmp
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/amb/so/git/tmp/.git/
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ echo "foo" > bar
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ mkdir baz
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ echo "baz" > baz/bob
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ echo "bar" > .gitignore
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ echo "baz" >> .gitignore
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ echo ".gitignore" >> .gitignore
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 4 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:12 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb    4 Dec  3 08:13 bar
drwxrwxr-x 2 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 baz
drwxrwxr-x 7 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:12 .git
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb   19 Dec  3 08:14 .gitignore
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ ls -la baz
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb    4 Dec  3 08:13 bob
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ git clean -df
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 4 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:12 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb    4 Dec  3 08:13 bar
drwxrwxr-x 2 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 baz
drwxrwxr-x 7 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:12 .git
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb   19 Dec  3 08:14 .gitignore
amb@nimrod-ubuntu:~/so/git/tmp$ ls -la baz
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 amb amb 4096 Dec  3 08:13 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amb amb    4 Dec  3 08:13 bob
```

Comment: Hi. You said `git clean -df` doesn't remove ignored files, which is not consistent with my experience. When I do `git clean -df`, ignored folders will also be deleted. This is what I wanna avoid.

Comment: @user1187195 I've just tested it and posted the results. `git clean -df` (at least on my system) does not remove ignored files or ignored folders.